# How to properly align text between table columns in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, alignment

I'm working with a large table in Microsoft Word 2010. It's a pretty simple table, consisting of two colums.

In the left column, I have keywords. Those keywords are linked to a specification (portion of) text on the right column. I currently typed the keywords just using hard enters. However, when changing things within the table, that means the keywords misalign pretty quickly making me manually set them back to the right position every time, deleting 'Enters' or typing extra 'Enters'.

Is there any way to "link" the keywords in the left column to the specific text in the right column, so they stay aligned properly when changes are made in or to the table?

An example of a table like this can be found here:
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way of doing this is to split the table into several rows and add the keyword and the description in the same row. It looks like you don't want any horizontal lines in your table, so make sure that the top and bottom borders of the inner cells are disabled.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do the trick. Pretty simple! Why couldn't I think of that? :-) It does require a lot of reformatting however, since "drawing tables" often messes up the layout completely, so manually adding rows and moving the text around is better. But in the end it'll work. Thanks.